# Présent vs passé simple

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, style-de-rédaction

Bonjour !
Je suis en train de rédiger une petite histoire et je me suis demandé si je peux utiliser le passé simple et le présent simultanément.

Par exemple : "...il ouvra la porte, elle répondit..."

Puis dans un autre passage : " Après avoir entendu la parole, Pierre quitte la chambre et ... "

Comment: Bienvenue sur French SE.  « Il *ouvra », c'est « il ouvre » si tu veux l'employer au présent, c'est une coquille ?  J'hésite à réviser [edit] sans savoir le temps du verbe désiré.

Comment: ou « il ouvrit » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il est possible de rédiger un texte au présent ou alors de le rédiger au passé simple (voire même au passé composé), mais il doit y avoir une cohérence dans l'ensemble du texte.
Une fois qu'on a choisi un temps pour la rédaction, il faut s'y tenir. Si plusieurs temps sont employés, on a alors un texte qui apparait incohérent, qui donne l'impression d'être mal écrit et surtout qui peut gêner la compréhension du lecteur.

A noter que pour l'écriture d'un récit, le passé simple est la norme. Si on souhaite rédiger un récit en utilisant un autre temps, il serait utile de se demander "pourquoi ?" et d'être sûr qu'on a une bonne raison de le faire.

Answer (score 1):

L'imparfait et le passé simple sont utilisés dans les récits ([français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-14751.php)).

> L'imparfait est le temps de la description, on l'emploie pour exprimer une action passée dont la durée est indéterminée.
>
> > ex: La neige tombait.
>
> Le passé simple est le temps de la narration, on l'emploie pour exprimer une suite d'actions.
>
> > ex : Ali Baba vit une troupe de cavaliers.

Le présent peut être utilisé en même temps que le passé simple mais pas sur un pied d'égalité avec le passé simple¹ ou l'imparfait parce que le présent n'est pas un [temps de base](http://lettres.clg.free.fr/?Temps-de-base-du-recit)  du récit  ([français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-46614.php)) ; cet usage particulier du présent est appelé "*présent de narration*".

> Le présent de narration : il s'emploie pour rapporter des actions passées en les rendant plus vivantes, il donne une impression de direct.
> ex: Il aperçut un de ses camarades qui traversait la rue. Il se précipite vers lui et l'appelle.

On voit dans la phrase de l'exemple que le passé simple, temps du récit, est utilisé pour "apercevoir", puis que l'imparfait est utilisé pour "traverser" (durée indéterminée de l'action de traverser); finalement le présent est utilisé pour "appeler".

¹ <sub>(ou le passé composé, qui est de nos jours de plus en plus employé comme temps de base du récit à la place du passé simple)</sub>